# How to preserve scientific knowledge following a major nuclear war

Tags: society, technology, worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources, nuclear-war

Suppose we are at the brink of a nuclear war between two major nation-states. These states have many thousands of warheads and the war is likely to lead to a nuclear winter that would kill most of those who survived the initial bombings. However, let's assume that some people are able to survive.

Suppose some country is concerned with ensuring that the surviving few are able to preserve a good portion the world's  scientific heritage and technological capabilities. It is willing to expend quite a bit of resources to do this. What should it do?

Some ideas I've had are the following:

1. Build large nuclear bunkers and pay many scientists who have very diverse and far-ranging research interests to live in nuclear bunkers. They can leave, but only if replaced with other scientists, so that at any point in time, some scientists will be protected. Questions: what kind of scientists would be best? Which countries should these bunkers be located in?
2. Pay non-scientists to sit in bunkers too. Society is more resilient to decline if many survive. These people would be trained in developing food sourcing for during the nuclear winter, and possibly with the job of restoring electricity grids and other critical national infrastructure systems. Question: what training would these non-scientists need?
3. Create data centers that archive much of the internet including scientific publications. These data centers would have to be secured and be supplied with some energy supply, such from as geothermal sources (sunlight wouldnt do, given a nuclear winter). Question: How could one best store archive what's on the internet?

Comment: How best to archive what's on the internet? For how long? Decades? Centuries?

Comment: Print the internet. On paper. Or better: print the relevant bits. The result would typically be called a library. Paper can last ages. and the only thing needed to make the information useful is somebody who can read the language.

Comment: Hello and welcome to worldbuilding. Yes, I know this is your third post but I feel a slight introduction is in order. Let me point out one thing in particular: **This is not a forum**. Worldbuilding SE — just like all other sites on Stack Exchange — is a **Question & Answer** resource. Your posts are not really questions, they are more like attempts at starting up a discussion. This is something that works great for our [**chat**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/), but not for the main site.

Comment: Store it in space / on the moon. It's recommended to split this one into 3 different questions because of the nature of SE

Comment: I usually recommend that question posts be organised as follows: **Premise**, **Problem**, **Query**. The **Premise** is where you explain what the world you are building is about.... give some basic information what it is about and the rules that govern it. The **Problem** is where you as an author have gotten stuck; it is something that makes it so that you cannot continue authoring your world. The **Query** then is the actual question, which — if answered — will solve the problem. Try writing your posts as such, and see if that nets you more and better answers. :-)

Comment: I am voting to close this because this is much too broad and opinion-based. Too many "It depends" factors. And it grossly fails the "Write A Book" test because you can easily write a whole book about the efforts to preserve knowledge for the dystopian after-world.

Comment: @MichaelK thanks for your feedback. I understand, can I delete the post?

Comment: @tbes There is no need to delete it.

Comment: I hope you are aware that most of the Internet is porn...

Comment: Just some info about *closing* questions: at first a question will be put on hold if 5 community members with 3,000 reputation think it's off-topic in its current form. Any edit from the author will then automatically send it to a special reopen review queue, where anyone with 3,000 reputation can vote to reopen or leave closed, judging the on-topicness of the newest version. If 5 members vote to reopen it gets reopened. It's a normal process, especially on WorldBuilding. Only after a week or so without any activity from the author a question will not be sent to the queue, but voting possible

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to look at https://lifeboat.com/
This foundation has made some fairly detailed plans for archiving knowledge and avoiding a number of possible doomsday scenarios. And are actively working to implement those plans.

The lifeboat foundation has considered the possibility that asteroids, nanotechnology, nuclear war, chemical, or biological agents (as well as a few other scanarios) could result in the end of human life, or end of current state of science and technology from loss of life on a large enough scale to lose skill sets needed to keep the machines running.
And they have begun planning and fund raising to implement these plans including the preservation of knowledge mentioned by the OP.

I am not current on these plans, but the last time I looked, it was based on optical storage because of the density, low cost of the media, and the ease of building replacement readers in a worst case scenario.

Comment: Nice, but link only answers are discouraged in case the links go bad. Any summaries of some relevant plans you could add to your answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, even after the edit you still don't provide details that answer the question.

Comment: I responded to the question as posted, and completely ignored the "some ideas I've had section" on the basis that it would be too much to answer. But "preserve a good portion the world's scientific heritage and technological capabilities" by building a wiki of files and committing them to optical disk is a reasonable answer. Sorry if you are not pleased with it.